# $a^{-1}\times b^{-1} = (a\times b)^{-1} $ Proof

Tags: field-theory

How would one go about prooving the following equation with the axioms of a field?

$a^{-1}\times b^{-1} = (a\times b)^{-1} $

Would this be a proof:

$a^{-1}\times b^{-1}\times (a\times b) = b^{-1}\times a^{-1}\times (a\times b) = b^{-1}\times (a^{-1}\times a)\times b = b^{-1}\times (1)\times b = b^{-1}\times b = 1 \rightarrow a^{-1}\times b^{-1} = (a\times b)^{-1}  $

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I guess $\times$ is the product in the field you are working with, right? This seems a bit unusual notation to me, I am more used to $a\cdot b$. (Especially since sometimes we use the notation $n \times a=\underset{\text{$n$-times}}{\underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only have to identify what axioms you're using at each step (you actually uses axioms several times in each step, but that's fine - it's quite trivial). Already at the very start you're using associativity without realizing it - by multiplying three factors without parentheses you're almost assuming associativity.

An alternative would be to use the fact that it's a ring and $ab=ba$. Using the formula for inverse in a ring (if it exists):

$$(a^{-1}b^{-1}) (ab) = (a^{-1}b^{-1})(ba) = 1$$

Comment: Yeah, that was another question of mine. If I multiply 3 factors without parantheses I would first have to proof somehow that: $a\times b\times c$ is equal to $(a\times b)\times c$, right?

Comment: @LionIsLoose I don't know, but there could be a convention that you're supposed to do the calculation from left to right, but I don't think that assumption is too common (in maths). It's probably more common to use mandatory parentheses when the operator is not associative.